# Prevent database from being dropped during test iterations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using Rspec to test my code against a legacy database (no migration, no schema etc). Is there a way to prevent the database from being dropped between iterations? Thanks.

```
config.before(:suite) do
 DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner gem.

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil  # will not do any db cleaning
```

I hope you can test on a local db before trying it on the real legacy db!

Comment: I tried that but even so, as soon as I hit 'rake' to test, my database was still wiped out. I updated the original question with how I set the database strategy.